# Check whether an operator is overloaded in C++

Tags: c++, templates, error-handling, operator-overloading

I'm writing a template function for shuffling, and I want to check whether the 'less than' operator is overloaded on an arbitrary data structure before trying to use it. It this possible?

Comment: If you need to compare using the less-than operator, just do it. It's up to the user of your class or function to make sure the correct overloads exists.

Comment: As for "shuffling", what's wrong with [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)?

Comment: Well, the shuffling is not the point. I wanted to know if it's possible to check if an operator is overloaded on an arbitrary data structure.

Comment: Ask a specific question and post a [MCVE] to illustrate.

Comment: just dont check **before** using the operator. Using the operator **is** the check. If the class doesnt implement it, the user will get a (more or less) clear error message from the compiler

Comment: @user463035818: This sort of thing can be useful if you have a complex nest of templates and want to catch the problem further up the call stack for better handling.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's at compile time anyway, not sure if there are so many cases where this might be too interesting... Possibly more the example given in the accepted answer: providing a fallback solution if the operator does not exist. There might be reasons for preferring not do define the operator ourselves together with the template...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use the Detection Idiom to test whether `T < T` is well formed at compile time.

For readability, I'm using [experimental::is_detected](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected), but you can roll your own in C++11 with the voider pattern.

First, a class it works for which a `<` is well formed:

```
struct Has_Less_Than{
    int value;  
};

bool operator < (const Has_Less_Than& lhs, const Has_Less_Than& rhs) {return lhs.value < rhs.value; }
```

And then one where it isn't:

```
struct Doesnt_Have_Less_Than{
    int value;
};
// no operator < defined
```

Now, for the detection idiom part: we try to get the type of the result of a "theoretical" comparison, and then ask `is_detected`:

```
template<class T>
using less_than_t = decltype(std::declval<T>() < std::declval<T>());

template<class T>
constexpr bool has_less_than = is_detected<less_than_t, T>::value;


int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_less_than<Has_Less_Than> << std::endl; // true
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_less_than<Doesnt_Have_Less_Than> << std::endl; // false
}
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8M0TOpzWRYNoygsL)

If you have C++17 available, you can take advantage of [constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) for your test:

```
if constexpr(has_less_than<Has_Less_Than>){
    // do something with <
}
else{
    // do something else
    
}
```

It works because constexpr if is evaluated at compile-time, and the compiler will only compile the branch that was taken.

---

If you don't have C++17 available, you'll need to use a helper function, perhaps with tagged dispatch:

```
template<class T>
using less_than_t = decltype(std::declval<T>() < std::declval<T>());

template<class T>
using has_less_than = typename is_detected<less_than_t, T>::type;

template<class T>
void do_compare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs, std::true_type) // for operator <
{
    std::cout << "use operator <\n";
}

template<class T>
void do_compare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs, std::false_type)
{
    std::cout << "Something else \n";
}

int main()
{
    Has_Less_Than a{1};
    Has_Less_Than b{2};
    
    do_compare(a, b, has_less_than<Has_Less_Than>{});
    
    Doesnt_Have_Less_Than c{3};
    Doesnt_Have_Less_Than d{4};
    do_compare(c, d, has_less_than<Doesnt_Have_Less_Than>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U1zO0YfzLOAkNq4e)

---

If you have C++20 available, we can easily accomplish this with a [concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints):

```
template<class L, class R=L>
concept has_less_than = requires(const L& lhs, const R& rhs)
{
    {lhs < rhs} -> std::same_as<bool>;
};
```

This concept can be read as "Given two possibly different types, the concept is `true` if calling `operator<` between two const references returns a boolean. Otherwise it is false."

You could fiddle with it a bit, e.g., changing `same_as` to `convertible_to` (if for some reason you expected `operator<` to return an integer that could be converted to a boolean.

[C++20 Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/e8oYmRF974IYR0CC)

The concept can be used instead of `enable_if` (`requires my_concept<T>`), and is also convertible to a compile-time boolean value like `true_type` and `false_type` are (so it could be used in `if constexpr`)

Comment: Oh, I totally misunderstood the question. Good answer!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thanks. I misunderstood at first, too. It sounded like OP just needed to try to use `<` and then the compiler would tell them if it was possible, but then I saw the templates tag.

Comment: This is great, thanks!

Comment: @AndyG: I don't even know if I could explain the nonsense I was thinking 

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nowhere in the question is written that compiling fine even if the overload is missing is a requirement. So no, I don't think you misunderstood the question, and your comment is absolutely fine... Andy's merits are coming up with what was never asked explicitly, but was *intended* to ask...

Comment: @Aconcagua: If I understood the question, then, it was completely by accident.